# git-lfs-migrate with Bitbucket gives "/objects/batch 501 (Not Implemented)"

Tags: git, bitbucket, git-lfs

I'm trying to migrate our Git repo to LFS like this:

```
java -jar git-lfs-migrate.jar -s our-repo.git -d our-repo-small.git -l https://user:password@bitbucket.example.com/bitbucket/scm/example/our-repo.git "*.jar"
```

LFS is enabled for the repository, but I'm getting:

```
[main] INFO git.lfs.migrate.Main - LFS server: Batch API request exception
ru.bozaro.gitlfs.client.exceptions.RequestException: https://user:password@bitbucket.example.com/bitbucket/scm/example/our-repo.git/objects/batch - 501 (Not Implemented)
        at ru.bozaro.gitlfs.client.Client.doRequest(Client.java:315)
        at ru.bozaro.gitlfs.client.Client.lambda$postBatch$7(Client.java:118)
        at ru.bozaro.gitlfs.client.Client.doWork(Client.java:252)
        at ru.bozaro.gitlfs.client.Client.postBatch(Client.java:118)
        at git.lfs.migrate.Main.checkLfsAuthenticate(Main.java:113)
        at git.lfs.migrate.Main.main(Main.java:66)
[main] ERROR git.lfs.migrate.Main - LFS server: Invalid base URL
```

We're on Bitbucket v4.6.2 but I couldn't find anythig related in the Bitbucket changelog since than.

Am I doing something wrong? Or does git-lfs-migrate use a feature that's not yet implemented by Bitbucket? If so, is there any workaround? I assume I'm not the first one doing this :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I managed to work around this thanks to [a comment in the git-lfs-migrate issue tracker](https://github.com/bozaro/git-lfs-migrate/issues/29#issuecomment-298447320):

```
git clone --mirror ./path/to/repo.git
java -jar git-lfs-migrate.jar \ -s repo.git \ -d repo-converted.git \ "*.psd"
cd repo-converted.git
git fsck
git remote add origin https://github.com/user/repo-converted.git
git push origin master # (or git push --all origin)
git lfs push --all origin
```

Basically you just create all LFS files locally and then push them manually to the LFS server.

Comment: You need to swap the "add" and "remote" in the 5th command line:

Answer (score 0):

The following works for me:

```
java -jar git-lfs-migrate.jar \
-s repo.git \
-d repo-converted.git \
-g https://usename:password@bitbucket.org/user/repo-converted.git \
"*.png"
```